# How to pause Thread execution

Tags: java

How to pause execution of some Thread. I have Thread t and I have two buttons, PAUSE and CONTINUE. On pause I need to pause thread execution and on continue to thread start execution from point where stoped before. What to put in listeners?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472868/how-to-pause-program-until-a-button-press/5472999#5472999

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Threading in Java is cooperative, which means you can not force the thread to stop or pause, instead you signal to the thread what you want and thread (= your logic) does it itself.

Use synchronized, wait() and notify() for that.

1. Create an atomic flag (e.g. boolean field) in the thread to be stopped. Stoppable thread monitors this flag in the loop. Loop must be inside `synchronized` block.
2. When you need to stop the thread (button click) you set this flag.
3. Thread sees the flag is set and calls `wait()` on a common object (possibly itself).
4. When you want to restart the thread, reset the flag and call `commonObject.notify()`.

Comment: The first answer that makes sense +1

Comment: If you are using a atomic boolean to signal when a thread should either continue or pause execution, why does the loop need to be in a synchronized block?

Comment: Correction: this is redundant in this particular case, because there is only one thread that can own the common object's monitor: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/why-wait-notify-notifyall-must-be-called-inside-a-synchronized-method-block/127

Comment: Duh. Correction on correction: you need `synchronize` in any case even if there is only one thread. When `object.wait()` is called current thread MUST own the object's monitor. This is achieved via `synchronized`. Without it a `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown. Also, `notify()` must also be also called inside synchronize block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at the wait() and notify() methods against java.lang.Object

Answer (score 0):

There is a wait and await that you can call. Await sounds closer to what you are looking for. Why do you need to pause the execution of some thread? If it for something other than homework there may be other solutions.

Comment: pausing the execution of some thread is a perfectly fine, and valid solution. I use this in practice all the time...

Comment: Sorry, I was not trying to imply that it is not good to do. Though you have to account for spurious wake-ups, missed signals, etc. What I meant was that depending on the reason why this needed to be done there could be other solutions that better fit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same logic as thread pool. where the threads are in a pool until they are invoked to perform some action submitted to the pool

Comment: The question is about stopping an existing thread, not about starting a new thread. Thread pool has nothing to do with it.

Comment: when ever wait is pressed wait on some object and when ever proceed is pressed call notifyAll on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private boolean isPaused = false;


public synchronized void pause(){
    isPaused = true;
}

public synchronized void play(){
   isPaused = false;
   notyfyAll();
}

public synchronized void look(){
   while(isPaused)
      wait();
}

 public void run(){
     while(true){
        look();
        //your code
 }
```