# Is there standard implementation for thread block/resume in java SE?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I need to block execution of a thread until resumed from another thread. So I wrote my own implementation using `wait()` method. Which seems to be working, but it is far from simple.

Is there any ready to use solution? Preferably in java SE 6? Or do I have to use my own implementation? I couldn't find any.

***Update***
More specifically. I need work->block->external release->work->end behavior from thread 1 and ability to release block from thread 2.

Comment: See the `java.util.concurrent` package,

Comment: What are your threads doing/waiting for? A better alternative to `wait/notify` is to use the higher level constructs from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: Far from simple?  I can't imagine its being simpler than shown in [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).  Simply put:  `while (!ready) monitor.wait()` in one place, `ready = true; monitor.notify()` in another place.

Comment: @VGR The tutorial isn't real-world example. There is no on interrupt logging, no volatile control variable, wrap to class and `block()`, `release()` methods, plus some imports. It all adds up to 60 lines of code in my case. Much bigger than `Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);`, `semaphore.acquire();` and `semaphore.release();` lines.

Comment: If you use wait/notify, you should not be using a volatile variable, or any java.util.concurrent class.  Though, as someone else suggested, you may find CountDownLatch easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by other answers, I found two solutions:

**First**:

Create `Semaphore` with no (`0`) permits:`Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);` in first thread. And share reference to it with your second thread.

Do some work in the first thread and call `semaphore.acquire();` when you wish to stop execution.

Some time later call `semaphore.release();` from second thread to unblock the first one.

**Second:**

Create `CountDownLatch` with initial count `1`: `CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch (1);` And again, share reference to it with both threads.

Call `countDownLatch.await();` when you wish to block execution of the first thread.

The first thread can be resumed by calling `countDownLatch.countDown();` somewhere in the second thread.

Answer (score 4):

have a a look at the classes in `java.util.conucurrent` ...
`CountDownLatch` might be a solution for your problem if i understand your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to block execution of a thread until resumed from another thread.

Not enough information.  Do you need an on/off switch that is controlled entirely by one thread and obeyed by the other?  That might be a good application for a Turnstile:  [Pause thread from another thread(s) and also stop/start it yet from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923288/pause-thread-from-another-threads-and-also-stop-start-it-yet-from-another-thre/30924072#30924072)

Or do you need "one-shot" behavior?  (i.e., the "background" thread does one thing each time the "foreground" thread gives it permission to go.)  That would be a good application for a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`.

Or, do you need some other behavior?

Comment: I need work->block->external release->work->end behavior from thread 1 and ability to release lock from thread 2. Both `CountDownLatch` and `Semaphore` suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

using an ExecutorService and calling invokeAll might also be an option.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

this way lets you also specify a timeout in which all tasks should have been finished. Which is generally a very good idea, if you want to have a responsive application.

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned his requirement that "I need to block execution of a thread until resumed from another thread.". So, `ExecutorService` even though a good API but will not meet his requirement.

Comment: Hi hagrawal, if you look at the documentation of the method I mentioned you will find that it blocks as long until all tasks are executed or the timeout is reached. It is not a very typical executorservice  method,l however ;)